# Rails 4 - unused eager loading. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, eager-loading

I have this query:

```
@cars = Car.select('COUNT(id) AS grouped_cars')
                          .includes(:services, :industries)
                          .within(distance, origin: params[:search_dealer])
                          .where('...')
                          .group('cars.brand')
```

Then, in the view:

```
<% @cars.each do |car| %>
  ...
  <% car.services.each do |service| %>
    <%= service.name %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

But the `Bulet` gem alerts **Unused eager loading - remove includes(:services, industries)**

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Here's the code where are used `industries`:

```
<% industries = car.industries.map(&:name_slug).join(',') %>
```

Comment: i don't get how that `select` can actually be used to do anything except that it returns counts?!

Comment: There are grabbed all the fields from the table, `select` is not compatible with `includes` - means that the select part just grabs some extra fields (the counts).

Comment: I think, you should use select later in the query. I believe, the `includes` is not used in the query

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you are not using 'industries' with the block, thus you have made an unnecessary query to the industries table which is not used in your template

```
<% @cars.each do |car| %> 
<% car.services.each do |service| %>
<%= service.name %>
<% end %>
```